Deployed React + Node.js App on Heroku: Frontend Loads Indefinitely with No Errors
I've deployed a full-stack app with a React frontend and a Node.js/Express backend to Heroku. The app loads indefinitely on https://sirunchat.com or https://sirunchat-ee34e597efd8.herokuapp.com/ with no visible errors, even though it runs fine locally.
Project Structure:
Frontend: React app in client folder, built using react-scripts.
Backend: Node.js/Express in the root folder.
Database: MongoDB connection via MONGO_URI environment variable (using MongoDB Atlas).

What I’ve Tried:
Static File Serving:
    In server.js, I serve the static React files from client/build:

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const webPush = require('web-push');

const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const friendInvitationRoutes = require('./routes/friendInvitationRoutes');
const groupChatRoutes = require('./routes/groupChatRoutes');
const { createSocketServer } = require('./socket/socketServer');

// Load environment variables
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Configure CORS for cross-origin access
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://sirunchat.com' : '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
      return res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`);
    }
    next();
  });
}

// MongoDB connection
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
mongoose
  .connect(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Database connection failed:', err);
    process.exit(1); // Exit process if database connection fails
  });

// Configure VAPID keys for Web Push
const vapidPublicKey = process.env.PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY;
const vapidPrivateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY;

webPush.setVapidDetails('mailto:chosen@goufer.com', vapidPublicKey, vapidPrivateKey);

// JWT authentication middleware
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (!token) return res.sendStatus(401);

  const tokenString = token.split(' ')[1];
  jwt.verify(tokenString, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
}

// Routes
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/invite-friend', authenticateToken, friendInvitationRoutes);
app.use('/api/group-chat', authenticateToken, groupChatRoutes);

// Serve static files from the React app's build directory in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client/build');
  app.use(express.static(buildPath));

  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(buildPath, 'index.html'), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Create HTTP server and initialize socket connection
const server = http.createServer(app);
createSocketServer(server);

// Start server
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Environment Variables:
Verified MONGO_URI and other sensitive environment variables on Heroku using heroku config.

Database Connection:
MongoDB Atlas IP whitelist includes all IPs.
Logs confirm a successful connection to MongoDB when deploying, but the page still loads endlessly.

Client-Side Connection:
REACT_APP_API_URL is set to https://sirunchat.com/api in my .env.production file for production builds.

Heroku Logs:
heroku logs --tail shows no errors but confirms that the server is running on the correct port.

Question:
How can I troubleshoot why the frontend of my deployed app is stuck on loading without displaying errors, despite a successful local setup?
